# Central Limit Theorem Problem 8.21.6

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I am having difficulty with the following problem found on page 389 of *Elementary Probability* by D. Stirzaker, a hint or solution would be greatly appreciated:

> An aeroplane has $120$ seats and is full. There are $120$ inflight meals of which $60$ are fish and $60$ are pasta. Any passenger, independently of the rest, prefers pasta with probability $0.55$, or prefers fish with probability $0.45$. Show that the probability that $10$ or more passengers will not get their first choice is approximately $0.234$ (you are given that $\Phi(0.734)=0.7676$ and $\Phi(2.94)=0.9984$).

Comment: This feels like a normal approximation to a binomial problem.  $N(np,np(1-p))$

Comment: Thanks Karl, I thought as much. The issue for me is in calculating p - the probability person i does not get his first preference. I calculate it as 1/2, but when I follow through on the calculation using CLT, I get a non sensical answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of fish dishes ordered.

The probability of a passenger ordering fish is $0.55$ and is independent from passenger to passenger.  The situation can therefore be modelled by a binomial distribution of $X\sim B(120,0.55)$.

Note that the mean $X$ is $120\times0.55=66$ and the variance is $120\times0.55\times0.45=29.7$.

To approximate the binomial distribution with a normal use $X\sim N(66,29.7)$.

If at least $70$ order fish then at least $10$ are disappointed so you want $p(X\ge70)$

If you want more let me know.  Hope that helps

Comment: Your clarification is greatly appreciated - thank you Karl. I was wrong in assuming the meals were assigned at random.